# How to make a list from a list of tuples. I need from [(1, 2), (3, 3)] get [1, 2, 3, 3]

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this code

```
from typing import List, Tuple
n = 2
a = [1,3]
b = [2,3]
def zipper(a: List[int], b: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    zippy = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        zippy.append((a[i], b[i]))
    return zippy
print(zipper(a, b))
```

How can I create a regular list from this?

Comment: Do you want `sorted(a+b)` perhaps?

Comment: Isn't this a regular list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just keep it simple:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    zippy.append(a[i])
    zippy.append(b[i])
```

You do know there's `zip` in python, right?

Comment: How would you use zip in this requirement ?

Comment: Yes, i know there's zip in python

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just realised from the title of the post that you want `[1, 2, 3, 3]` from `[(1, 2), (3, 3)]`:

```py
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zipper(a, b)))

>> [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I _think_ the wanted result is that of `list(chain(zip(a, b)))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I phrased my question incorrectly. I needed the def zipper function to return a list of items